# Add blurred edges to a div but keep the content inside transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, blur

[image: A blurred image]

I have a slider, I want the edges of the content div to have a blur effect, blurring the background image behind it. The background image is from the parent div. As you can see the content inside it is not blurred and you can see through the background, but the edges are blurred. Any ideas on how to achieve this effect?

It doesn't matter if it's CSS only or mixed with JavaScript, I'm using React anyways.

Comment: Do you have an existing HTML structure you want to apply this style to? (If so please include it in the question)

Comment: you could approach it with `outline`: https://jsfiddle.net/u6xreack/

Comment: @GrafiCode That works if you just want an overlay, but I don't think there's any way to apply a blur with `outline`.

Comment: it's kind of a "fake blur", it's actually rgb color with alpha.

Comment: What's your code? Have you looked up CSS `blur()`?

Comment: I have the code and it is in React, but what @GrafiCode did is pretty much the structure.

Comment: @tobiv I have, The problem with blur is, it blurs the entire parent, and there is no way as far as I am aware of that makes the child separate from that effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using `clip-path` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)) and `backdrop-filter` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)) Both are relatively new rules, so check your browser compatibility.

We use the clip path to select a 10% "frame" around the inside of your box, and then apply a 10px blur with `backdrop-filter`

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/502/1000/1000.jpg?hmac=L-KRcO3K2TOyaVRnDSO13QrAo73FnHrIBApbvfakTOw')
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px 100px;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 10% 100%, 10% 10%, 90% 10%, 90% 90%, 10% 90%, 10% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px #fff solid;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="content"> Your text here</div>
</div>
```

Here's a version using CSS variables so you can quickly/easily adjust the blurred border thickness. Just change the `--b` CSS variable:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/502/1000/1000.jpg?hmac=L-KRcO3K2TOyaVRnDSO13QrAo73FnHrIBApbvfakTOw')
}

.box {
  /* The border thickness (Can be a percentage or pixel value) */
  --b: 6px;
  /* Work out the inverse value for the right/bottom sides of the clip path */
  --b2: calc(100% - var(--b));
  
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px 100px;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, var(--b) 100%, var(--b) var(--b), var(--b2) var(--b), var(--b2) var(--b2), var(--b) var(--b2), var(--b) 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px #fff solid;
  top: var(--b);
  left: var(--b);
  right: var(--b);
  bottom: var(--b);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="frame"></div>
  <div class="content"> Your text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, the use of clip-path is perfect

Comment: This is a nice answer, Unfortunately, my background image is on a div and not the whole body element. I think using a fixed background is a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Akar As long as the background is behind the `.box` element, this should work. It doesn't need to be on the body, that was just for the sake of this demo.

Comment: I've used your technique in another way and it's working now, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the polygon thickness without adjusting the whole shape?

Comment: @Akar I've added another version (At the bottom, hidden by default) which uses CSS variables to make it pretty easy to change the border thickness. Just adjust the `--b` variable and it should handle everything else for you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `clip-path` if you set the same background image on the content box. *Caveat:* `background-attachment` needs to be `fixed`. And if you use `flex` for all the boxes, just setting `position: absolute` on the content would be enough to center it on top.

```css
html, body, .bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bg, .blur-box, .content-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg, .content-box {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/1/1920/1080/) no-repeat fixed 0 0 / cover;
}

.blur-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
 
.content-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="blur-box">
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
      TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```